# How to scale a bar plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my bar plot to take up less space, currently there is a lot of white space which is not neccessary. I would like the bins to be a lot closer than they currently are. And since there are only two categories in the X axis I do not see why there is so much space between them. - increasing the bin width would make white space go away, but then the bins become unnaturally large.

Code:

```
# Creates plot to show response-rate
hubspot_ordering %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Replied)) +
        geom_bar(color = "black", 
                 fill = "steelblue",
                 stat = "count",
                 width = 0.1,
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
        xlab("Kommuners respons på e-post og oppringing") +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Besvart",
                                    "Ingen respons")) +
        ylab("Antall kommuner") +
        theme(element_line(size = 0.5)) +
        theme_bw() -> plot_response_rate
```

Output:
[image: Graph showing big gap between bins.]

Comment: If you drag your plotting window to be narrower, the bars will stay the same width but the white space will be removed.

Comment: This is true, but when using ggsave() it does not matter how it looks in the plotting window.

Comment: Yes, but you can set the width and height of the output to whatever size you want. Just reduce the width if there is too much whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `aspect.ratio` in your `theme` using the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(x=factor(LETTERS[1:2]), y=sample(1:100, 2))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, width=.1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2/1) +
  labs(x="", y="")
```

Output `aspect.ratio=2`:

[image]

Output `aspect.ratio=1`:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code, and there I can see a clear difference between aspect ratio 1 and 2, but with my own code there is no difference.

Comment: @OptimisticKnut, Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"
), class = "factor")